# mTLS Google Cloud not providing certificate authorities in TLS handshake

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, mtls

I'm using mTLS with [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/mtls) for a load balancer. I have defined a [TrustAnchor](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-mtls-ccm) defining my supported root CAs. The expectation would be that a [certificate_authorities](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.4) extension is included in the `certificate_request_context` extensions to inform the client which CAs are supported so that the client can use a correct key and certificate signed by this CA. But GC is not including this. Is there a flag or option how to enforce this?

Since the client is supporting multiple servers the client is using this for the certificate lookup, i.e. a fixed selection and presentation of the client certificate does not work.

Comment: AFAIK. Google Cloud's load balancers do not support customizing the certificate_authorities extension in the certificate_request_context for mTLS. Since clients have multiple servers, I'm afraid you can't do a fixed selection and presentation on your client certificate. I believe an alternative approach should be considered.<br>

Comment: AFAIK @YvanG. is correct. I have done a lot of work on configuring and testing mTLS with Google load balancers. The end result is that mTLS works very well but I expect there will be more features in the future. Consider creating a feature request [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and sharing your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer. Please also consider what @JohnHanley mentioned regarding [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

AFAIK. Google Cloud's load balancers do not support customizing the certificate_authorities extension in the certificate_request_context for mTLS. Since clients have multiple servers, I'm afraid you can't do a fixed selection and presentation on your client certificate. I believe an alternative approach should be considered.

Comment: I added a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/293679166